# Spring boot override application properties in test

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

If I have a `appplication.properties` like:

```
url=someUrl
user=userOne
password=ABCD
```

But if I want to be able to set the password when testing to something else, lets say:

```
password=someTest
```

How do I do that?

I need to do this in one test

```
@Test
void checkSomething{
    //change/override password before calling someMethod only for this test
    someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Did you create application.properties file in src/test/resources ?

Comment: @Habil Yes  I did.

Comment: Ok, try this: @SpringBootTest(properties = { "key=value" })

Comment: @Habil Any way to apply only for one test method instead of the whole test class?

Comment: Add application-testing.properties in resource folder inside test and access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a testing profile file something like `application-testing.properties` and specify the overridden properties there.

Now while running the application you can specify use profile using
`-Dspring.active.profiles=testing`

Answer (score 1):

create another application.properties under src/test/resources thats all you need,
if you want to get properties to use in one method you can do i without involving spring :

```
InputStream input = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(yourproperties-path);
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
prop.load(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways.

1st way: **Spring Profile**

aplication.yaml:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
---
spring.profile=dev
url=someUrl
user=userOne
password=ABCD
---
spring.profile=test
password=someTest
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTestClass {...
```

2nd way: **SpringBootTest Properties**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "password=someTest" })
public class MyTestClass {...
```

Comment: Any way to apply only for one test method instead of the whole test class?

Comment: @nopens i updated my response to load properties for one method

Comment: I don't see no changes. May be you forgot to edit your answer :-) ?